# Tkinter Button disabled background

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to define button color when disabled. Currently, I change the color of the button every time I change the button state.

`button.config(state=DISABLED, bg="grey")`

And then I need to change it back every time. Which is quite annoying.

`button.config(state=NORMAL, bg="red")`

There is an option for foreground `disabledforeground` so I expected there is a sister function for background, which is not.

```
button = Button(
    master,
    bg="red",
    disabledbackground="grey",
)
```

Is there some other option how to define `disabledbackgroud` eg. via theme or something like this?

Comment: How do you change the state ? Do you use another button or manually ?

Comment: You can use `ttk.Button` which supports different background colors in different states.

Comment: @acw1668 ok I will try, there is something like `50.2. ttk style maps: dynamic appearance changes`, it is probably exactly what I looking for

Comment: @AyyoubESSADEQ it can be both. Usually, it is some external event, so I change it "manually"